# How can I reference the type `module` in Python?

Tags: python

If I import a module in Python, then the type of the module is, unsurprisingly, `module`. However, I'm not sure sure how to reference this type directly. Here by "directly" I mean by writing something like `module` rather than taking the `type` of a module. For example, in the following shell interaction, I can test whether an object `obj` is an `int` by writing `isinstance(obj, int)`, but evidently I cannot test whether `obj` is a module by writing `isinstance(obj, module)`.

```
>>> import random
>>> type(random)
<class 'module'>
>>> isinstance(random, module)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'module' is not defined
>>> isinstance(random, 'module')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
>>> isinstance(random, type(random))
True
>>> isinstance(1, int)
True
>>> isinstance('Hello, World!', str)
True
```

Comment: `import types`, then use `types.ModuleType`.  Types for pretty much all standard objects that don't have an otherwise-accessible name are in that module.